# Transfer data from image column to varbinary SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 SQL databases. Both databases has '`Product`' table.
I want to transfer all the products from DB `A` to DB `B`.

My issue is in DB `A` ; `prductImage` data type is '`image`'.
in DB `B` `prductImage` data type is `'varbinary(MAX)`'.

After transferring When showing the image using DB 2 will that be a problem?

Comment: When data is converted from a string data type(ex: image) of unequal length, SQL Server pads or truncates the data on the right. When other data types are converted to binary or varbinary, the data is padded or truncated on the left. Padding is achieved by using hexadecimal zeros. So, converting any value of any type to a binary value of large enough size and then back to the type, will always result in the same value if both conversions are taking place on the same version of SQL Server. So in scenario given there shouldn't be a problem ..:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188362.aspx

Comment: Except there won't be any real conversion happening - image is variable binary anyway, they've essentially just changed the name because there is no reason to restrict it's use to images only.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. If you have any application code that retrieves this data then you'll need to make sure any parameters you pass to stored procs and the like are updated to use the new data type (and the procs themselves are updated to accept the new datatype). It's pretty unlikely you'll have an equalities or any other operations on such a field so that will probably be your lot.

Short answer is suck it and see - testing will soon show up anything that needs changing.